# Cannot retrieve database connection information from a separate file

Tags: php, mysql

This has been asked numerous times and I've went through numerous solutions on stack overflow but no solution managed to fix my issue (even though it's so trivial). I've got a file called utilities.php which returns an array with the connection information and I call the array to a variable `$cfg`. I can `echo` the `$cfg` variable and it returns the correct information but when I'm trying to connect to the database and submit a query it fails to connect to the database.

Code:

```
<?php
    $cfg = include('utilities.php');

    mysqli_connect($cfg['host'], $cfg['user'], $cfg['password']);
    mysqli_select_db($cfg['database']);

    mysqli_query("INSERT INTO comment (userID, commentText, adventureID, dateTime) VALUES('$userid', '$commentInput', '$adventureid', '$date')");
?>
```

utilities.php :

```
<?php
    return array(
        'host' => 'host',
        'user' => 'user',
        'password' => 'password',
        'database' => 'database'
    );
?>
```

Comment: What fails? Connection to the database? Selecting the database? Running the query?

Comment: It doesn't connect to the database. The connection information gets printed correctly though, as I tried to echo it.

Comment: What exact error do you get?

Comment: It returns a blank error message. I tried adding 'or die('Cannot connect to the database') after the connect statement but still a blank error message.

Comment: `mysqli_select_db()` requires db connection and the query also; there *"explained"* ;-) read the manuals on those. and the one on getting the real errors http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: you're also open to an SQL injection.

Comment: then these are unknown `'$userid', '$commentInput', '$adventureid', '$date'` and if there's something that MySQL is kicking about. check for errors. I can't emphasize on that enough.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Try [mysqli_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) for error message.  Without the message from mysqli we can't hope to know what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forget to pass connection param to mysqli_query function:

```
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
    $query = "INSERT INTO comment (userID, commentText, adventureID, dateTime) VALUES('$userid', '$commentInput', '$adventureid', '$date')";
    mysqli_query ($link , $query );
```

> mixed mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode =
>   MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )
>
> mixed mysqli::query ( string $query [, int $resultmode =
>   MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )

[PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Comment: Can you explain how this works?

Comment: @hoeRIZON I added reference, you can read it.

Comment: I've done what you suggested. Still no luck. Edit: works!

Comment: Partially your solution and a missing semicolon.